# Open phone dial pad

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a call from my application but I want open the phone dial pad before directly making a call. But with custom url scheme It is calling on the number directly.

Is there any way to open it? I found nothing related to this except for CallKit but that article is too overwhelming.

I tried this

```
let url : URL = URL(string: "tel:90634904")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I also tried this as per suggestion

```
let url : URL = URL(string: "tel://90634904")!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
          UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Both of this making a call directly without opening a dial pad where I can edit it.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to launch the phone app *without* passing a phone number to call.

Comment: @chirag90 those solutions are not working

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried and what is not working from them solutions, and then we may be able to help you.

Comment: updated the question. please check

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No. With that code I am not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

I have quickly tried to make a simple app with button click event to call. Have look at the below code.

```
@IBAction func callButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let phone = 0123456789
    if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phone)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to add the following in info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>tel</string>
</array>
```

Output i can see

[image: Output image]

P.S Also you will need to run this on an actual device and not a simulator.

Comment: did this work for you?

Comment: this thing is coming. But i want it to open in dial pad where i can edit number if I wish or select different sim to call